# is the prototype will work on factory function?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects, prototype, function-prototypes

```
function person(firstName, lastName) {
  return {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
  };
}
person.prototype.displayFullName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
let person1 = person("Virat", "Kohli");
let person2 = person("Sachin", "Tendulkar");
console.log(person1)
console.log(person1.displayFullName())
console.log(person2.displayFullName())
```

*Can we add a new function to the factory function using prototype*

Answer (score 0):

To make a constructor call use the `new` keyword.  Properties added to the object bound to `this` will be accessible by the object returned by the constructor call `new Person(..)`.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

let person1 = new Person('Virat', 'Kohli');
let person2 = new Person('Sachin', 'Tendulkar');

console.log(person1.fullName());
console.log(person2.fullName());
```

Comment: i am asking about factory function. You are saying about constructor function. Can we do it on factory function or not.

Comment: If by factory function you are referring to the function defined in your post then no, there is no prototype linkage.